# calculating the total page offset

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code I have to work with. How do I use the IF condition here to check the total page offset is grater-than 75% ?

```
function getLocalCoords(elem, ev) {
    var ox = 0, oy = 0;
    var first;
    var pageX, pageY;

    // Walk back up the tree to calculate the total page offset of the currentTarget element.
    while (elem != null) {
        ox += elem.offsetLeft;
        oy += elem.offsetTop;
        elem = elem.offsetParent;   
    }
        alert(ox)
    if (ev.hasOwnProperty('changedTouches')) {
        first = ev.changedTouches[0];
        pageX = first.pageX;
        pageY = first.pageY;
    } else {
        pageX = ev.pageX;
        pageY = ev.pageY;
    }   
    return { 'x': pageX - ox, 'y': pageY - oy };

}
```

Comment: Define your terms.  Total page offset = ox + oy?  75% of *what*?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Total page offset of an image on canves. `.var c = document.getElementById('maincanvas');  
 c.width = image.back.img.width;
 c.height = image.back.img.height;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simplest terms you'll need width and height of what you want to compare against.

```
percent_from_let = 100 / width  * x;
percent_from_top = 100 / height * y;
```

So something like:

```
/*
 * Report percentage x/y
 * */
function pst_report(pos, el) {
    var 
    // Dimensions
    dim = {
        w : el.offsetWidth, 
        h : el.offsetHeight
    },
    // Percent
    pst = {
        w : 100 / dim.w * pos.x, 
        h : 100 / dim.h * pos.y
    },
...
```

#### » [A (somewhat bloated) Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/48EwA/) «